# Is there a way to allow multiple synchronisation errors on heroku connect mapping?

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I am always getting postgresql error on `sfid` field because of unique restrictions after mapping and a bad SF synchronisation (so that field stay blank).

After second SF synchronisation errors I can't save other row.

Please help

Comment: Did you try to fill the `sfid` field with something before inserting new one ? and can you add some logs ?

Comment: No this is the Salesforce Id, we cannot create it before Salesforce

Comment: To fix your pb you can create like a small `18 length uid`  to fill `sfid` before the SF synchro, it allows you to continue saving other row while there are some synchro errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to save rows without getting `UNIQUE` errors on `sfid`,
try to create `18 length uid` to avoid blank field (x2 blank fields in postgreSQL is considered equal)

node.js:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

let uuid = uuidv4();
record.sfId = uuid.substring(1, 18);
```